# Hiding/Showing Drop Down menus depending on another option

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to make it so when a person selects an option from a drop down menu, another drop down menu shows up. So if I have a drop down menu with 3 choices, "Vancouver, "Singapore","New York". When a user selects Vancouver a drop down menu shows up with a couple of options, if they select new york another drown down menu shows up. To make things complicated I am also using php as its going to be running things on the server side eventually.

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "function getDropDown(sel){";
echo  "hideAll();";
echo  "document.getElementById(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value).style.display ";
echo  "= 'block';";
echo "}";

echo "function hideAll(){";
echo  "document.getElementById(\"vancouver\").style.display = 'none';";
echo  "document.getElementById(\"singapore\").style.display = 'none';";
echo  "document.getElementById(\"newyork\").style.display = 'none';";
echo "}";
echo "</script>";

echo    "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td align=\"right\">";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "<select name=\"optionDrop\" onChange=\"getDropDown(this)\">";
               echo "<option value=\"\">Please Select</option>";
                echo "<option value=\"vancouver\">Vancouver</option>";
                echo "<option value=\"singapore\">Singapore</option>";
                echo "<option value=\"newyork\">New York</option>";
            echo "</select>";
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td align=\"right\">City</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<div id=\"vancouver\" style=\"display: none;\">";
            echo "<select name=\"optionDrop\" >";
                echo "<option value=\"\">Please Select</option>";

            echo "</select>";
            echo "</div>";

echo "<div id=\"singapore\" style=\"display: none;\">";
//echo "<select name=\"optionDrop2\">";
  //              echo "<option value=\"\">Please Select2</option>";
  echo "Sing";
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id=\"newyork\" style=\"display: none;\">";
  echo "New York";
echo "</div>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Right now when I select the option "Vancouver" a drop down menu does shot up, and when selected other options a text shows up. However if I uncomment the lines

> ```
> //echo "<select name=\"optionDrop2\">";
>   //              echo "<option value=\"\">Please Select2</option>";
> ```

Then nothing works anymore. No matter what option I select nothing shows up. I am completely stuck and cant figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: why do you write the html like that :( makes me sad

Comment: You can use jQuery to grab the dropdown's value and then do one of two things: (1) have another dropdown be created on the fly, (2) have an existing dropdown whose CSS display value is none be set to become visible. jQuery will help you build your form up based on the user's response. And please, please, please don't echo out all your HTML. If this is PHP, just type in the HTML normally. PHP pages can be coded just like HTML pages - just utilize PHP tags strictly where PHP code is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum... first of all I'll give you a hint you might have begged for many years ago:

Closing a php tag within a php file won't break your code.
If you want to display only HTML like you are doing in the code you posted, just do the following:

```
<?php
    $variable = "test";
    // Some random things blabla.
?>
<span class="test">
    <?php echo $variable; ?>
</span>
<?php
    $something = "something_else";
    // Some other php
?>
```

About your problem, there you go:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GxytE

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! My only question is how do I combine the CSS and Jquery files to all work together?

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem? Could you explain more?

Comment: I get everything that is going on in the link you showed me. I just don't understand how to put the three parts together to make them work

Comment: Yes I am plan to use what you gave as a reference to write what I need. What I am struggling right now is actually using what you gave me to work. Like I am not understanding how to link the html, css, and jquery together to reproduce what you gave me.

Comment: Just output the HTML in your PHP file, put the CSS in your stylesheet and put the javascript wherever you want (though if you put it before the html is loaded, it is required you put it in a `jQuery(document).ready(function(e){ /* Code here */ });` code snippet).

Comment: Just to get this working I put the CSS part behind <style></style> tags and I put the jquery behind <script></script>. I only see one drop down box (w.o CSS tags all of the boxes are there). But when I click an option nothing happens, so I think it is the jquery. Any suggestion on what the issue might be?

Comment: Display the console error logs to see what is going on. Dis you incluse jQuery in your page? Maybe try to replace jQuery by a $.